# Line chart does not connect dots if they have gaps in values between in serie object

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jsfiddle

I have a regular chart, and sometimes for example you do not get values in some series ( y value ) it ends up being null, but my goal is to go through all series and if he does not find in next serie Y value to move on to next and connect the dots.

```
{
                "drilldown": false,
                "y": null,
                "name": "Febbraio",
                "datetype": "string"
            },
            {
                "drilldown": false,
                "y": 0,
                "name": "Marzo",
                "datetype": "string"
            },
            {
                "drilldown": false,
                "y": null,
                "name": "Aprile",
                "datetype": "string"
            },
            {
                "drilldown": false,
                "y": null,
                "name": "Maggio",
                "datetype": "string"
            },
            {
                "drilldown": false,
                "y": 0,
                "name": "Giugno",
                "datetype": "string"
            },
```

At the moment i have
[image]

And what i am trying to do is to connect grey dots with one line and black dots with one line.
Anyone have an idea what am i doing wrong ?
You can find my fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/zg9paq6e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the option `connectNulls`.

It can be applied to an individual series or all series by using `plotOptions`.

I added this to your series definition to get a line even when information is missing:

```
series: [{
  connectNulls: true,
  ...
}]
```

**Working JSFiddle**(where I used connectNulls for one series)**:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/uL3cmpjv/

**API on connectNulls:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.connectNulls

Comment: I have no idea how you managed to find and get to know this but you saved my life !
Thank you !